# Basic question - how to open a file

Tags: gazebo-all-versions

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I've been using gazebo for all of 2 days, and I'm sure this is a basic question, but how do I open a file?

The File menu has Save world, Save world as, Save configuration, Clone world, and Quit.  No "Open."

I was going through a tutorial when Gazebo crashed and exited.  I was saving as I went along.

I have Gazebo version 11.0.0 on Ubuntu 18.

I really did search around before asking!

TIA!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/24506/basic-question---how-to-open-a-file/) by [wmeitzen](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/23919/wmeitzen/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2020-02-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

There's no way to load a saved world from the menu, see [this issue](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issues/158/add-load-world-option-to-menu).

You should load the world at startup by passing the file path to Gazebo, i.e.

`gazebo /path/to/world.sdf`

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2020-02-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [wmeitzen](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/23919/wmeitzen/) on 2020-02-26**:
Just what I needed to know.  Thank you!